# Evaluating a line integral over a very complicated vector field

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis, vector-fields

> Let $F(x,y,z)=(f_x +xye^{xz^2},f_y + x^2e^{xz^2},f_z + 2x^3ye^{xz^2})$ where $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}$ is a $C^1$ function such that $f(x,y,z)=f(-x,-y,-z)$. Compute the work of $F$ through the curve parametrized by $\sigma:[0,\pi]\to \mathbb{R}^3, \sigma(t)=(\sin t (1+e^{t^2}),\cos t, t(\pi-t)^{4/3})$.

I'm incapable of solving this exercise. I'd be grateful to anyone who can provide any hint whatsoever.

Comment: Whoever gave you this is quite cruel. Notice that $\sigma(0) = (0,1,0)$ and $\sigma(\pi) = (0,-1,0)$. You can rewrite $F$ as $\nabla f + xe^{xz^2}(y,x,2xy)$. Use the property you have to show that the line integral of the left term is $0$. But I don't think anything can save you with the integral of the right term, not clever application of Stokes' theorem, not symmetry arguments, not anything.

Comment: Do you know if the first coordinate of $\sigma(t)$ is supposed to be $(\sin t)(1 + e^{t^2})$ or $\sin(t(1+e^{t^2}))$? The way it is written is ambiguous.